# When my carousel animates to 10,000+ pixels, it flickers. Is it a jQuery issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jcarousel, carousel, pixel

When my carousel animates past 10000 pixels, it flickers through a bunch of elements.

http://blossomsbnb.com/2011/test.php

I'm using jCarousel Lite: http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/

Is this a known jQuery issue? My first guess is that it's a jCarousel Lite thing, but nothing in their code suggests it might break at 10,000 pixels. It does it on all browsers.

This is my first time posting on SO so I apologize if I do something wrong, but any help would be awesome.

Comment: I cannot give you and answer cause i'm on ipad now ... but it does the same also on ipad, so it's not a computing power limit or similar stuff ...

Comment: Seems like a bug in the plugin. It is animating from 0 to 11000px instead of 10000 to 11000.

Comment: To add to the fun, if your slider is wider than 32,766px, Opera will wrap the rest of your content to the next line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you hit a [bug in jQuery](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/7287). Upgrade to 1.6.2 and it works fine. As I said in the comment previously, it seems to reset to `left: 0` before animating.

Comment: Totally fixed it. Thanks 100%

Comment: @Thio, if it "totally fixed it", click the checkmark beside it to mark it as the answer that fixed your problem.